# How to prevent GridView from updating if value has not been changed?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 Gridview's, one of them is updatable one is not. I'm using the built in update functionality. When you update one row, sql moves the data to the 2nd Gridview where the edit option is not available.

My problem is if you click Edit, then click Update WITHOUT actually changing the text box value, it updates sql with the same data and the row moves to the other Gridview. At which point users are unable to change that value for 24 hours.

How can I fix this?

thanks

mike

Comment: you do this by writing the code and since you don't show us what you're doing sounds like you're gonna be on your own until you do.. also this is not that difficult btw..

Comment: I used the built in functions of the GridView. There is no code, its a parameter you toggle.

Comment: and we are supposed to know what you're doing how...??

Comment: I thought I explained it. The gridview has an option to edit the data for you automaticially. but it lets you do this even if the data has not changed. I need to prevent it from allowing the update if the data has not changed

Comment: I added an answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is what was going on. I was thinking that the GridView was doing the updating. I don't know why I was thinking the GridView had anything to do with it. The GridView only pushes values to the data source that actually does the updating.

So when you look at the markup of the DataSource it was running the UPDATE statement that I had set up. The UPDATE was just that, an UPDATE. It did not matter if the data was the same or not.

So I simply changed my UPDATE statement to include an IF to see if the name field was the same or not. When you click "update" on the GridView, yes it still runs the update statement, but if there are no changes, the statement does not update any new data.

Here is the markup for the SQLDataSource, youll see the sql statements that are in it. That is what I had to fix

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="constring" 



        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RegisteredVisitors] ([ResidentName], [ResidentAddress], [VisitorNumber], [VisitorName]) VALUES (@ResidentName, @ResidentAddress, @VisitorNumber, @VisitorName)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE ([ResidentName] = @ResidentName AND [Date] <  (SELECT DateAdd(SECOND, -86400, getdate())))" 
        UpdateCommand="IF NOT (SELECT [VisitorName] FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK) = @VisitorName BEGIN DECLARE @i INT =  (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([VisitorNumber]),0) + 1 FROM [RegisteredVisitors]) UPDATE [RegisteredVisitors] SET [VisitorName] = @VisitorName, [Date] = GETDATE() WHERE [PK] = @PK UPDATE RegisteredVisitors SET [VisitorNumber]  = @i , @i = @i WHERE [PK] = @PK END;" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource_Selecting1">



        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="ResidentName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int64" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```